# MVC Razor Override Property Captions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to override the caption generated by the two MVC 3 Razor extensions below. I would like to show "Is Enabled" instead of "IsEnabled".

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsEnabled)
```

and

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsEnabled)
```

My property is decorated as follows:

```
[DisplayName("Is Enabled")]
public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
```

The `LabelFor` method seems to respect the `DisplayName` attribute; it works just fine. However, the `DisplayFor` method **does not** pick up the `DisplayName` attribute.

Any ideas on how I can override the caption of a property for both Razor methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing title and content (or name of a property and its value)

`DisplayFor` is for the content (value of the property of the instance), so shows true or false (or a checkbox checked or not) for a boolean.

`LabelFor` is... a label (kind of title), so it will show  the name of the property (IsEnabled if you don't put a DisplayName attribute), and the value of the DisplayName attribute if it exists

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and clarification. I'm very new to MVC/Razor.